# PHP repeating of an image on a page

Tags: php

I made a php program to repeat an image on a page in a square box.

The image repeats 100 times in a row and then again 100 times vertically.. that means total 100x100 images are repeating in that square box. The size of one such repeating image is 10x10 pixel.

Now the problem is when the site is to be tested on localhost, the page hangs, when it is tried to be opened, and after it is loaded on scrolling up and down it is slow and hangs a bit.

I used nested for loops to get the image repeated. The code for same is:

```
<?php
  for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
    {for($j=1;$j<=100;$j++)
        {
            echo '<div id="imagebox">';
            echo "<img src='images/image.png'>";
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
  ?>
```

Guys what could be the problem??

Thanks in advance for any possible solution.

Any alternate programming technique?

Comment: Why the JS and jQuery tags?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve overall here?

Comment: The `id`-attribute of an HTML element needs to be unique, you use `imagebox` 10,000 times...

Comment: Alternatives could include jQuery or building a single image using GD.

Comment: Do you have a stylesheet applied to these elements? By the way: you can’t have 10000 elements with the same ID; IDs need to be unique in a document.

Comment: @paul I mentioned in the question.. I want to make a box to show the images 100x100 times and hence i was repeating the images

Comment: @Peter Wooster
1. What is GD? 
2. I already know about making single image which cant be done
3. Can u show some jquery code?

Comment: You are saying what your solution is, "100x100 images" but not what the requirement is.

Comment: I would build this in GD as previously mentioned if you are experiencing lag. I am not asking what you are trying to achieve with this task - i am asking what the application of it is.. do the images need to be clickable.. and so on?

Comment: @gumbo I just simple css code like float:left.. 
& what do u mean by unique ID's?

Comment: @paul i want that on hovering the each image user see the name of image named by its ith location.. So this code.. any alternative?

Comment: There is no reason that this loop should hang, but what you are doing will not give you a 100x100 grid because the `<div>` is repeated on each iteration. Incidentally, if you are trying to load 100x100 images (which is quite a large number of images), the page may hang because your browser might get a bit upset.

Comment: Your code is putting the same id on 10000 images, you must use a different id for each image.

Comment: @user1999428 An ID is to distinctively identify a single element. If you have multiple elements on the same document with the same ID, it’s not unique any more. The behavior for that situation is rather undefined.

Comment: @techfoobar JS and Jquery because i want to get this achieved from JS and jquery so that problem is solved..

Comment: This is all a little non-sensical.

Comment: @user1999428 - Ah, ok. Would have been clearer if you had mentioned specifically that you were looking for a JS/jQuery answer to this one in the question itself.

Comment: @techfoobar do u have any solution for same?

Comment: @PeterWooster What i tried i mentioned above.. But not working completely

Comment: You haven't tried any jQuery or JS.  Have you fixed the ID problem?

Comment: @user1999428 - It is *surely possible* to have JS dynamically create the image elements and insert them into the DOM. That should be straight forward. *But*, having 10000 image elements will very likely slow down the page regardless of whether its populated from the server side or the client side.

Comment: @techfoobar I understand what you said.. But is there no solution of getting it done without getting it hanged? any other programming technique? my target is to have the name of each image separately.. so i have to repeat them anyhow..

Comment: @PeterWooster do i have to add id like this? 
echo '<div id="imagebox" . i>;'

Comment: Put the values of i and j in the ID, eg: imagebox0x0, imagebox0x1

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V9j5v/1/ - This won't hang the browser - but not sure if this would be good user experience still.

Comment: @techfoobar's  Fiddle does the trick. As has been said, it won't hang, but it's still loading a lot of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try fetching the image dimensions and then setting the height and width of the container div equal to 100 times of height and width of the image (respectively) and then just use CSS background-repeat property to repeat the image on x and y axis. This solution might work as you are trying to repeat a single image. 
See it in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/vzX9q

The HTML:

```
<div id="img"></div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgSrc = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100";

  $("#img").css({
    background: "url("+imgSrc+") repeat"
  });

 var newImg = new Image();
 newImg.src = imgSrc; 

newImg.onload = function() {
  var imgHeight = newImg.height;
  var imgWidth = newImg.width;

  $("#img").css({
    width : imgWidth*100,
    height: imgHeight*100
  });
}
});
```

Comment: OMG. Exactly what I llok for.. thanks a lot :)